# Access Denied error while accessing dir/files from remote machine using roboCopy command

Tags: powershell, remote-access, robocopy

I'm trying to access files stored on remote computer using roboCopy command. I've full access to that dir and manually can access those but when using robocopy I'm getting access denied error see error sniped below.

```
[exec] INFO: Creating PSSession on didnaruina6.apac.sas.com
     [exec] Access is denied
     [exec]     + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\didnacj01ina6...10014\LAXAG-2.8:String) [Test-Path], UnauthWARNING: Caught Exception Exit 1
     [exec] orizedAc
     [exec]    cessException
     [exec]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
     [exec]     + PSComputerName        : didnaruina6.apac.sas.com
     [exec]
     [exec] ERROR: Source \\didnacj01ina6.apac.sas.com\Sandbox\SQLDB\010014\LAXAG-2.8 does not Exist
     [exec] At C:\Tetris\modules\G3\Scripts\Invoke-G3RoboCopy-SandBox.ps1:52 char:3
     [exec] +         Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
     [exec] +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     [exec]     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (ERROR: Source \... does not Exist:String) [], RuntimeException
     [exec]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ERROR: Source \\didnacj01ina6.apac.sas.com\Sandbox\SQLDB\010014\LAXAG-2.8 does not Exist
     [exec]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Below is the code which gets executed when call is given to roboCopy.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
            Param([string]$VerbosePreference,$Server,$Source,$Destination,$Params)
            If(!(Test-Path $Source)) {throw "ERROR: Source $Source does not Exist"}
            Write-Host "INFO: Starting RoboCopy Archana...."
            $RoboCommand = "Robocopy `"$Source`" `"$Destination`" $Params /NC /NFL /NS /NDL /NP"
            Write-Verbose "Executing [$RoboCommand]"
            Invoke-Expression -Command $RoboCommand
            $RoboCopyExitCode = $LASTEXITCODE
            If ($RoboCopyExitCode -gt 7 -and $RoboCopyExitCode -ne 9 -and $RoboCopyExitCode -ne 11){
                Throw "ERROR: RoboCopy Exit Code $RoboCopyExitCode"
            }

        } -ArgumentList $VerbosePreference,$Server,$Source,$Destination,$Params
```

Can't we use roboCopy for copying data from remote machine to local machine? Do we need to give some special permissions to make that possible?

Comment: Might seem a bit daft, but do you have both NTFS permissions as well as share permissions? When you say "I've full access to that dir and manually can access those" Are you viewing the files locally on the remote server or accessing through the fileshare?

Comment: I can access those using given path on which they are located \\machineName.apac.sas.com\Sandbox\SQLDB\010014\LAXAG-2.8 . And I had asked that person to give read/write permissions to me when he shared that c:\SandBox with me, which he has given.

Comment: What's wrong in this question.. :( why there isn't any solution provided? Am I not clear in my question or nobody uses powershell now days?

Comment: It doesn't look like a scripting issue. From the error message, it looks like a permission issue which we can't really help with. Could you double check the permissions to ALL the files/folders in the source and destination locations and also update your question with your full code?